# Can nested cross validation be considered bootstrapping?

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, bootstrap

I am using nested cross validation with 5 inner and outer folds. Each of the folds are created using stratified shuffle splits from scikit-learn. Because I am using, can this be considered bootstrapping since I am not using k-folds for splitting, hence the training and test data in the folds could possibly the the same for different folds?

Answer (score 0):

Stratified Shuffle split creates test sets that may overlap each other, if you refer to this part, than, 'yes', it could be seen as bootstrapping, as some samples/sets have the chance to be considered twice (but not with the same length, I refer to the individual values within the sets) or more:

The source states:

> So, the difference here is that StratifiedKFold just shuffles and
> splits once, therefore the test sets do not overlap, while
> StratifiedShuffleSplit shuffles each time before splitting, and it
> splits n_splits times, the test sets can overlap.

Image from the first source:
[image: Stratified]

See here:
https://xzz201920.medium.com/stratifiedkfold-v-s-kfold-v-s-stratifiedshufflesplit-ffcae5bfdf

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45969390/difference-between-stratifiedkfold-and-stratifiedshufflesplit-in-sklearn